# java variable scope issue

Tags: java

I'm getting confused at how java works with everything being a class.

I make a class `foo.java` and in the `main` method of `foo.java` I make an instance of `foo` (a class creating itself makes no sense to me but it seems normal in java ?)

Then I make a instance of another class `bar`, so I now have instances of `foo` and `bar` inside the `foo` class but how do I access the member variables of `foo` with the functions in bar?

`foo` is the processing code and `bar` is the ui and needs to see all the data in `foo` so it can display it.

Comment: A little sample pf code would be very valuable. Can you post both of your classes so we can see what you have written so far?

Comment: wouldn't it be more logical to have a foo object in your bar object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities. One is to construct `foo` with a `bar` instance:

```
public class Foo {
    public void someFooMethod() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
        bar.someBarMethod();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    private Foo fooLocalRefence;
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.fooLocalReference = foo;
    }
    public someBarMethod() {
        this.fooLocalReference.someFooMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, composition is always a better choice

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about *"a class creating its self makes no sense to me but it seems normal in java"*, because your terminology is wrong. What you are actually doing is to create an **instance** of class `Foo`. And `main()` is merely the entry point of the application, because the JVM simply needs to know where to start.

And if you want instances of two different classes to share information, you need to provide one of them with a reference to the other. Something like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the Java tutorials on the oracle site -> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Follow these and this will give you a better understanding of how to write applications in Java - writing code which you do not understand will cause you problems later in the development process .....

Answer (score 0):

First, the `main` method of `Foo` is probably `static`, so there is not an instance of `Foo` creating a `Foo`.

Second, `Foo` should expose its data via getter methods and `Bar` should access the data by calling the getter methods on the provided instance of `Foo`.

Comment: how does bar call the getter methods ? you just moved the problem not solved it

Comment: @Skeith I said that "Foo should expose its data via getter methods and Bar should access the data ... on the provided instance of Foo". The assumption is that the getter methods are public so Bar will be able to call them. This is exactly what Pablo posted (except his Foo method returns void).